# Why convert 0xffffffff to decimal is -1 in C?

Tags: c

I thought the result would be `(2**32 - 1)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  unsigned int a = 0xffffffff;
  printf("the size of int a %d\n",a);
  return 0;
}
```

but it gives me `-1`, any idea?

Comment: `%d` -> `%u`...

Comment: Don't lie to printf() about argument types and you won't be surprised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're asking `printf()` to interpret that value as a signed integer, whose range is `-(2**31)` to `(2**31)-1`.  Basically, the high bit is a sign bit.  Read about [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: If the high-bit *was* a sign-bit then 0x8000 should be -0 .. I think it's more clear (and less confusing in the long run) to avoid that term.

Comment: The high bit is set if and only if the number is negative, so I think it's fair to call it a sign bit.  The meaning of the *other* bits is a little more nuanced for a negative number, but that's why I linked to a page with the details.

Answer (score 9):

You're using the wrong format string. `%d` is a signed decimal int. You should use `%u`.

`printf` has no knowledge of the types of variables you pass it. It's up to you to choose the right format strings.

Answer (score 1):

The `%d` format specifier is used for printing **signed** integers, and since you're passing in `0xffffffff`, `printf` is correctly outputting `-1`.

The issue is that the `%d` specifier is for **signed** integers. You need to use `%u`.

```
printf("%d",0xffffffff); // Will print -1

printf("%u",0xffffffff); // Will print 4294967295
```

By the way, I would expect to see a compiler warning here -- something along the lines of *"printf() expects int value but argument has unsigned long int type"*, because most compilers detect the type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Because %d represents a signed integer. With a signed integer, the high bit (32nd bit) is set when the integer is negative, or not as the case may be. In 0xFFFFFFFF the high bit is set, so when casting to a signed integer, the result is negative. To treat the high bit as part of the number itself, use an unsigned type

```
%lu or %u
```